# Vim distro with both python support and xterm_clipboard

Tags: vim

I'm using Vim in combination with mono for ASP.NET development. The OmniSharp plugin requires python 2 support.

This suggest the vim.nox-py2 distribution. But vim.nox-py2 does not include the system clipboard support (-xterm_clipboard), which I find quite essential.

The vim.gtk3 distribution does include support for the system clipboard (+xterm_clipboard) but it doesn't have python 2 support.

Is there a way to have Vim support both python2 and the system clipboard in Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `+xterm_clipboard` doesn't provide "support for the system clipboard"; it's `+clipboard` that does. You get that feature with any `vim-gtk*`/`vim-gnome*` package.
2. `$ apt list vim` gives you a list of Vim packages. Among them you have these three packages that all satisfy your requirements:

   - `vim-gnome-py2`
   - `vim-gtk-py2`
   - `vim-gtk3-py2`